# How should i proceed with banking Application in Python

Tags: python, django, django-models

I know baisc Python and Django but not advanced. I want to make Banking Application for personal use.
it will have various type of accounts like saving account , Fixed deposits account. I need to calculate interests and put money automatically in accounts.

Is there any example of that type of application so that i can start.

Comment: This might not be a good idea. If you're just at a basic level, mistakes with security implications could leave your bank accounts exposed.

Comment: no no , its not at all linked with banks , i am just coding for my relative for his home use. he will be using on local server and i can get some practice as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the tutorials on djangoproject.com and go from there.

If you want to look at something already done go to: http://code.google.com/p/django-budget/ that should give you a great start.

Answer (score 0):

To create a banking application in Python and Django, you need to create a Django model. In the context of a banking system, there are two necessary models: the Account model and the Transaction model.

```
class Account(models.Model):

    ACCOUNT_TYPE = (
        ('Savings', 'savings'),
        ('Current', 'current')
    )
    ACCOUNT_STATUS = (
        ('Active', 'active'),
        ('Closed', 'closed'),
        ('Frozen', 'frozen')
    )

    FIXED_DEPOSIT = (
        ('Regular', 'regular'),
        ('Senior Citizen', 'senior citizen'),
        ('Corporate', 'corporate')

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_number = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
    account_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE)
    account_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ACCOUNT_STATUS)
    transfer_pin = models.IntegerField()
    fixed_deposit = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=FIXED_DEPOSIT)
```

These are the necessary fields for the Account model. You can add additional fields and design your own banking system, but these ones are required.

After creating an Account model, an account number and some fields should be created automatically when the user is created. In this case, we need to use a Django signal to create an Account model object whenever a user is created. The reason why we should use a Django signal is the simplicity in creating an Account model object. Imagine this is a social media app; each and every user has a profile. Do you think that allowing users to create a profile page manually is really a good idea? If yes, then users can create more than one profile page. That's why we wanted to use a Django signal to create an Account model for you automatically.

```
from .models import Account
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
import random
import string

#we should generate an account number for each user, we can't just create it manually.
def generate_account_number():
    start_number = '55' + ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=8
    return start_number

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
   
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_account(created, instance, sender, **kwargs):
    if created:
        transfer_pin = instance.transfer_pin
        account_status = 'Active'
        account_type = 'Savings' #you can edit that, but for this time, it should be a savings account.
        fixed_deposit = 'Regular' # you can also edit it, but for this time, it should be created with Regular.
        account_number = generate_account_number()
        #create an Account model automatically
        Account.objects.create(
            user=instance, 
            account_number=account_number, 
            account_type=account_type,
            account_status=account_status,
           fixed_deposit=fixed_deposit, transfer_pin=transfer_pin, account_balance=0
        )
```

To create a Transaction model, you need to create the necessary field like: amount, sender, receiver, account number, and timestamp, in this example, I created a sender and a receiver field and assign them to a CustomUser model with a different related name. In django model, when you define a sender and receiver in a Transaction model, you are likely modeling a financial or transactional system. Here's why you might need both of these fields:

1. The sender field represents the entity that initiates or sends the transaction. This could be an individual, a business, or any account that is transferring funds or resources. In a financial context, it might be the account from which money is deducted or withdrawn.
2. The receiver field, on the other hand, represents the entity that is on the receiving end of the transaction. This is the account or entity that is gaining funds or resources through the transaction. In financial terms, it's the account that receives money.

Having sender and receiver fields in your Transaction model provides a clear and structured way to handle financial transactions and ensure that you can track and verify the movement of assets within your application, It allows you to answer questions like:

1. Who initiate the transaction?
2. Who received the funds?

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3, editable=False),
    account_number = models.IntegerField()
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='who_send')
    receiver= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='who_receive')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now it time to create a Transaction view, and sent the Interest rate to a
super user account.

```
def transfer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        account_number = request.POST['account_number']
        amount = Decimal(request.POST['amount'])
        superuser_account = Account.objects.get(user='superuser username') # set this username to the admin username or your preferred account.
        sender_account = Account.objects.get(user=request.user)
        receiver_account = Account.objects.get(account_number=account_number)

        interest_rate = 0.02
        deduction = amount * interest_rate

        if sender_account.account_balance >= amount:
            sender_account.account_balance -= amount
            sender_account.save()

            receiver_account.account_balance += amount
            receiver_account.save()
  
            superuser_account.account_balance += deduction
            superuser_account.save()
            
            Transaction.objects.create(
                sender=request.user, receiver=receiver_account.user,
                amount=amount, account_number=account_number
            )
            return redirect ('Transfer')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Insufficient Funds')
            return redirect ('Transfer')
    return render(request, 'transfer.html')
```

This code checks if the sender account balance is greater than equal to the specified transfer amount. If the sender doesn't have enough funds, it sets an error message and redirects to a Transfer page. The code also check  if there are sufficient funds, the code will send the specified amount from the sender account balance and adds the same amount to the receiver account balance. It then saves these changes to the database. In this code,  there is interest_rate of 2% (0.02) and calculated the deduction based on the transaction amount. Then, i deduct the transaction amount along with the interest from the sender account.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to authorize the app to access your bank accounts. Look into the authorization frameworks they use such as OAuth. There are libraries you can use to integrate with those standard frameworks like Authlib.